# Why does $(this) works with .hover() but not with .ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-backstretch

So, I am trying to get backstretch.js to work with multiple divs that is loaded from the db.

but I can't get a separate image for each div.

This works perfectly, when I **hover** the boxes, the background shows up, but I wan't it to be loaded as soon as the page loads.

```
 $(".tournament-thumb").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).backstretch($(this).data("url"));
       }
);
```

I have tried this with **.ready()** without any result this it doesn't seem to register "$(this)" ? :

```
     $(".tournament-thumb").ready(
    function(){
        $(this).backstretch($(this).data("url"));
       }
);
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="tournament-thumb" data-url="images/image.jpg"></div>
```

Please help me... If there is any better way than this, please respond with that then :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready , It's better to read documentation of ready handler

Answer (score 3):

From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)**:

> The .ready() method can only be called on a jQuery object matching the current document, so the selector can be omitted

So you can only use `$(document)` for the `ready()` method.

Answer (score 0):

possibly best solution is to bind the delegation to the document object like

```
 $(document).on('hover','.tournament-thumb',function(){
    $(this).backstretch($(this).data("url"));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it with jQuery.each

```
$.each($(".tournament-thumb"), function() {
   $(this).backstretch($(this).data("url"));
});
```